# Loading Data from table with between timestamp

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracle10g

I'm having a Source tbl with a column timestamp (DD.MM.YYYY HH24:MI:SS)

Now I want to load data between, lets say, 01.11.2013 and 05.11.2013.

When I use i.e. the following:

> select count(1) from tbl where a.timestamp between trunc(to_date('1.11.2013', 'DD.MM.YYYY'))
>   AND trunc(to_date('05.11.2013', 'DD.MM.YYYY'))

So the output is 312.020

When doing a select count and grouping by DD.MM.YYYY I get a higher number for these days in sum than with the query above. What could be the reason.

Comment: Could you show both queries ? First you are talking about 1.11. and 5.11, then you are showing that timestamp has to be equal 1.11 and then you are talking about different number when you aggregate whole month. Please clarify.

Comment: i tried to clarify ;)

Comment: I assume that you don't use same WHERE clause for the GROUP BY or is it ommited altogether?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a little hard to tell but it seems like you're losing some or all of the data from the 5th because you're ignoring the time portion. When you do:

```
a.timestamp between to_date('1.11.2013', 'DD.MM.YYYY')
  AND to_date('05.11.2013', 'DD.MM.YYYY')
```

(I've removed the `trunc()` as they don't add anything), you're counting from `01.11.2013 00:00:00` to `05.11.2013 00:00:00`, *not* up to `05.11.2013 23:59:59` which might be what you're expecting.

You could compare with `trunc(timestamp)` instead but that can have performance implications. You could do:

```
a.timestamp between to_date('1.11.2013 00:00:00', 'DD.MM.YYYY HH24:MI:SS')
  AND to_date('05.11.2013 23:59:59', 'DD.MM.YYYY HH24:MI:SS')
```

... or:

```
 a.timestamp >= to_date('1.11.2013', 'DD.MM.YYYY')
  AND a.timestamp < to_date('06.11.2013', 'DD.MM.YYYY')
```

noting that the 'to' date in the second version is now the 6th, so that it goes up to but not beyond the end of the 5th.

---

I'm assuming from the description that your field is of type `DATE`; calling it `timestamp` is a bit confusing since there is a `TIMESTAMP` data type as well. If it is actually a `TIMESTAMP` then the second version will still work, but the first would need to take the fractional seconds into account and go up to `23:59:59.999999999`, and both should use a `to_timestamp()` call instead of `to_date()`.

```
a.timestamp between to_timestamp('1.11.2013 00:00:00', 'DD.MM.YYYY HH24:MI:SS')
  AND to_timestamp('05.11.2013 23:59:59.999999999', 'DD.MM.YYYY HH24:MI:SS.FF9')
```

Depending on the precision of your timestamp field, you might not need all the 9s, and could perhaps use `FF3` or `FF6`. More in [the docs](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/sql_elements004.htm#SQLRF51079).

Comment: true, its a real timestamp. this  where a.timestamp between to_timestamp('05.11.2013 00:00:00', 'DD.MM.YYYY HH24:MI:SS')
  AND to_timestamp('06.11.2013 23:59:59', 'DD.MM.YYYY HH24:MI:SS') worked perfectly

Comment: If it is a real timestamp then any records between `23:59:59.001` and `23:59:29.999` would still not be counted, so you should include that really - might be unlikely to have a record in that small window, but one day you might and it will be hard to work out why the count is very slightly wrong *8-)

Comment: well the timestamp is only DD.MM.YYYY HH24:MI:SS (so no milliseconds). I guess in that case it works fine